# Error in opening browser using selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/codes/python/script.py", line 5, in <module>
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

I referred the docs but there is not much info there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`webdriver.Chrome()` is constructor, not a field. It should be

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Thanks `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')`  worked